# Can we extends different layout in subview?

Tags: laravel-5

I had the following codes.

```
@if(isset($is_gift_card_site) && $is_gift_card_site)
    @extends('gift_card.layout.index')
@else
    @extends('layout.index2')
@endif

@section('content')
    //html
@stop
```

It works. But it will extend both layouts (duplicated). Any solution for this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ternary operator?

```
@extends(isset($is_gift_card_site) && $is_gift_card_site ? 'gift_card.layout.index' : 'layout.index2')
```

Or with a variable:

```
<?php $layout = isset($is_gift_card_site) && $is_gift_card_site ? 'gift_card.layout.index' : 'layout.index2'; ?>
@extends($layout)
```

Comment: Just check again. It doesn't work. It won't duplicate but always extend 'gift_card.layout.index'.

Comment: Try this then:
`<?php $layout = isset($is_gift_card_site) && $is_gift_card_site ? 'gift_card.layout.index' : 'layout.index2'; ?>`
`@extends($layout)`